# Оформление прямой речи с обращением

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, обращение

Можете сказать, как правильно? Я думаю, что 1-й вариант правильный, но я потому сомневаюсь, что, возможно, надо как-то же обращение *мама*, поставленное в конце прямой речи, обособить-то.

1. «Я не хочу есть это брокколи, мама», – сказал Леопольд.
2. «Я не хочу есть это брокколи, мама,» – сказал Леопольд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно же, верен первый вариант, но — с поправкой: слово [брокколи](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8) женского рода, поэтому надо использовать указательное местоимение "эта" (в падеже — "эту").

*«Я не хочу есть **эту** брокколи, мама», – сказал Леопольд.*

*Но миссис Элджин, представьте, имела наглость назвать **эту брокколи** убогим экземпляром и заявить, что она не собирается готовить ее* (А. Кристи).

В ПАС есть правило и подходящий пример с обращением:

> **§ 134.** Если прямая речь стоит **перед** вводящими ее **словами автора**, то после прямой речи ставится запятая и тире, а слова автора начинаются со строчной буквы: *«Мы всё прекрасно понимаем, Николай Васильевич», — съязвил про себя Солодовников, присаживаясь на белую табуретку* (Шукш.)...

А вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:
*«Спасибо тебе, **мама»,** — сказал матери Андерс, обнял и поцеловал ее* (М. А. Палей);
*«Я хочу поехать в эту школу, **папа»,** — сказал я отцу* (В. Савич).

[Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)

Answer (score 3):

Вы правы, правилен первый вариант:

***«Я не хочу есть это брокколи, мама», – сказал Леопольд***.

Запятая всегда ставится после кавычек, но перед — никогда.

А если перед закрывающей кавычкой стоит вопросительный знак, восклицательный знак или многоточие, то запятая и после кавычек не ставится.

См. **[«Полный академический справочник»](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)** под ред. Лопатина:

> **§ 134.** Если прямая речь стоит **перед** вводящими ее **словами автора,** то после прямой речи ставится запятая и тире, а слова автора
> начинаются со строчной буквы: *«Мы всё прекрасно понимаем, **Николай
> Васильевич**», — съязвил про себя Солодовников, присаживаясь на белую
> табуретку* (Шукш.). Если после прямой речи стоит вопросительный,
> восклицательный знак или многоточие, то эти знаки сохраняются, а
> запятая не ставится…

Answer (score 1):

Забавная ситуация с брокколи. Все грамматики и все словари утверждают, что это **женский род**. Будем им верить? А то как же!

А мне **не нравится** сочетание "эту брокколи", и что мне делать? Придумала!

*Не буду есть **эту** капусту брокколи. Не буду есть **это** блюдо брокколи. Не буду пить **этот** смузи брокколи.*

Поэтому можно сказать ***это брокколи***, если имеется  в виду блюдо, кушанье. А сырую капусту кто будет есть, если только сыроеды. Кстати, в приведенном в ответе примере персонаж только собирается приготовить что-то из **этой капусты** брокколи.

Другая ситуация. *Я не покупаю брокколи в пакетах, лучше взять развесную.* Здесь капуста **женского рода**.

Есть еще мн. число – **соцветия брокколи**:  Живешь, дышишь воздухом, ешь **сырые брокколи** без соуса и чувствуешь, что умрешь здоровым (Кира Сурикова, 2003).

А вот сочетание "эту/эта брокколи" в Нацкорпусе **не нашлось**, как и забавное сочетание "эту/эта кольраби". **Неблагозвучные** они какие-то.

Comment: Брокколи употребляется и в сыром виде. Смузи, кстати, приготовляется тоже из овощей и фруктов без термической обработки. Да, по-вашему получается и вправду забавно: *Не буду есть это кольраби!*

Comment: Если капусту нарезали и посолили, то это уже блюдо. Про род "смузи" я прочитала в статье https://ug.ru/yazykovaya-lovushka-v-kakih-slovah-putayut-rod-dazhe-gramotnye-lyudi/  Смузи – это достаточно современное явление для русского языка, поэтому словари пока не предлагают четкого толкования лексемы. Но в одном положении лингвисты точно сходятся: слово относится к мужскому роду, так как это густой напиток или коктейль.  Захотели с братом Кузей
Приготовить свежий смузи